# How to importing a specific Vuetify component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

When i try to import a specific vuetify components, the component base style is not imported.

Here is my parent component code which imports components from vuetify

- Webpack: 5
- Vuetify: 2.6.6
- VueJS: 2

```js
import {
  VBtn,
  VIcon,
  VTooltip,
} from 'vuetify/lib'

export default {
 name: 'Project',
 components: {
  VBtn,
  VIcon,
  VTooltip,
  },
}
```

Comment: Please, do not re-create questions without new details. The answer to this question highly depends on your environment (e.g. vuetify version, webpack version etc.). If you don't want to share these details here, maybe it would be better to ask question in [Vuetify Discord channel](https://community.vuetifyjs.com/).

Comment: Thank you I just updated the information

Answer (score 0):

you should always import components in vuetify.js like this

for example, to import the date picker:

```js
import { VDatePicker } from 'vuetify/lib/labs/components.mjs';
```